# Validar date time com jquery validate

Tags: jquery-validate

O titulo do post já diz tudo, tenho um  com a máscara dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm e gostaria de validar se o usuário digitou corretamente.
Já tentei criar usando o addMethod e não obtive sucesso. Alguém ai tem uma receitinha de bolo pronta?

Obrigado

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do código?

Comment: Coloca um `minlength = "16"` no campo